# How to catch a FileNotFoundException with Gradle's Exec task?

Tags: gradle

Inside my build script I have a few lines that collect some information about the state of the repo at build time and embed in the build. One such line is:

```
def gitBranchName = "git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD".execute().text.trim()
```

Now this behaves exactly as it should as long as *the developer has the `git` executable in their path*. If the developer doesn't have `git` in the path, the result is a build failure with `FileNotFoundException`. Having this information embedded in the build is *not* crucial. So what I'd like to do is to silently ignore the exception. Wrapping the above line in a `try/catch` block didn't help. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. The title of your question is about the [**Gradle** `Exec` **task**](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Exec.html), but in your example you only use the [**Groovy JDK enhancement method** `execute`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()). What functionality do you plan to use and how is it integrated into your build file?

Comment: I tried either, but was unable to catch the exception with either approach. I don't care how I execute the command as long as I can ignore the exception.